# includeInLayout does not work for griditem in flex 3.6

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using Flex 3.6 and I want to set the includeInLayout property to false for a GridItem, but it does not seam to have any effect. 
I have the following:

```
<mx:Grid width="100%" height="100%" id="appCore">
  <mx:GridRow width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">
      <np:NodePanel width="100%" height="100%" id="node1" idIndex="1" />
    </mx:GridItem>
    <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%" visible="{showAllPanels}" includeInLayout="{showAllPanels}">
    <np:NodePanel width="100%" height="100%" id="node2" idIndex="2" />
    </mx:GridItem>
  </mx:GridRow>
  <mx:GridRow width="100%" height="100%" visible="{showAllPanels}" includeInLayout="{showAllPanels}">
    <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">
      <np:NodePanel width="100%" height="100%" id="node3" idIndex="3" />
    </mx:GridItem>
    <mx:GridItem width="100%" height="100%">
      <np:NodePanel width="100%" height="100%" id="node4" idIndex="4" />
    </mx:GridItem>
  </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

When showAllPanels=false, the second row is, correctly, not shown and the first row expands the complete page. The right GridItem in the first row is not shown, but the left GridItem is not expanding the complete page. If I remove the right GridItem completely, the left GridItem expands the page completely.

Are there any tricks to get it working?

Comment: As a general rule includeInLayout is just a suggestion which the container must honor [or not].  Perhaps the Grid layout does not honor it.

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout sadly does not support includeInLayout.

There is an Apache Jira entry for it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-112

At the time of writing of this answer the Jira entry is in state Closed/Later since 2007-06-04 so it is probably postponed till end-of-time.